# WebFrame content not appearing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a simple little application I'm using to try to learn to use WebFrames in an OS X desktop application.

The WebFrame exists inside a window that gets opened by clicking a button in the main menu nib window.

I'm trying to just load a simple HTML String into the WebView when its window gets loaded, just to make sure everything is hooked up right.

Here is the h file for the window

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface WebReportView : NSWindowController

@property IBOutlet WebView *webView;

@end
```

And here's the m file including the code that I think should be loading the HTML string.

```
#import "WebReportView.h"

@implementation WebReportView

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [[self.webView mainFrame]loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body><h1>Foo</h1></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
}

@end
```

The window loads just fine, and I can see the WebView, but the content is not getting loaded into the WebView. The big bold "Foo" is missing.

Same thing happens if I try to load actual web content:

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
[self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
```

Nothing gets loaded into the WebView.

I know the loadHTMLString (or loadRequest) method is getting called because I put NSLogs before and after it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hey cutmancometh,
I am facing same issue. have you got any solution? please let me know... Its very urgent for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that you have created WebView Outlets and all connections are made.
Ensure that You have set WebView Delegate

```
 NSString *fullURL  = @"http://www.google.com";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webUrl loadRequest:requestObj];
```